# A randomly generated 20 character's alpha-numeric key

Tags: asp.net

How can i create A randomly generated 20 character's alpha-numeric key in asp.net
i need to save it i database on some link click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
string id=  Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").Substring(12); // CORRECTED was 20
```

Comment: Will it be different each time, when a client click on it?

Comment: Everytime generated will be different. Even if you create it in a loop.

Comment: But with the Substring(20) is it still GUARANTEED unique? A Guid is longer than 20 characters so there is no 100% guaruantee, or am i missing something? I agree the odds are small, but still..

Comment: Even with GUID, it is NOT GUARANTEED. Only the chance is slim. GUID makes 32 characters and we are taking 20 characters. It is only a matter of the risk, if he really needs unique then perhaps need to take 32 or even combine 2 GUIDs to make 64 charcters...

Comment: But, in actually it is giving 12 alphanumeric value only, why so?

Comment: Yes!! Use `Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").Substring(12);`

Comment: See the birthday problem. If you are going to need a lot of these you would be better using a base64 encoded random string to get more bits of entropy in. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_distribution

Answer (score 2):

```
var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789".ToCharArray();
var random = new Random();

string output = "";
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    output += chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
}
```

Comment: `Random` may not be random enough. :-(

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what your requirements are. What is the allowable set of characters, for example?

One simple option is:

```
string key = (new Guid()).ToString().Left(20);
```

Note: Guids on windows are cryptographically random. This wasn't the case historically but has been for a few years now.